# What is the relationship between r in signature and the public key

Tags: signature, raw-transaction, ecdsa

I've been reading about ECDSA in [here](https://www.instructables.com/Understanding-how-ECDSA-protects-your-data/#:%7E:text=you%20only%20need%20the%20%E2%80%98x%E2%80%98%20value%20(20%20bytes)%20for%20the%20signature%2C%20and%20that%20value%20will%20be%20called%20%E2%80%98R%E2%80%98).

Step 11 says that

> you only need the ‘x‘ value (20 bytes) for the signature, and that value will be called ‘R‘

Does that say that R is the x-coordinate of the public key.
But I don't see that happening in a raw transactions.

For the pizza transaction, it's scriptSig looks like that：

> 48

> 30450221009908144ca6539e09512b9295c8a27050d478fbb96f8addbc3d075544dc41328702201aa528be2b907d316d2da068dd9eb1e23243d97e444d59290d2fddf25269ee0e01

> 41

> 042e930f39ba62c6534ee98ed20ca98959d34aa9e057cda01cfd422c6bab3667b76426529382c23f42b9b08d7832d4fee1d6b437a8526e59667ce9c4e9dcebcabb

The first one is signature,the second one is the public key.
I don't see any relationship between the two items.

Answer (score 2):

> Does that say that R is the x-coordinate of the public key.

That is not correct.

The R value in the signature is the x coordinate of *a point*, but that point is not equal to the public key. Instead, it is the x coordinate of the public nonce used in the signature.

Answer (score 1):

And since this is a signature, there is of course also this relation:

```
G*m+Y*r == R*s
```

both sides of this equation evaluate to the point:
`(0x75c79891ca4248d78c84bac2d4a1d787d5a53d77044b1ab46e7de24f23e860dc,0x6b4c968c2bbba0fdec5f119d577b5be812c804a6ca4ea2858335af36685a8994)`

where:

- G is the generator point
- m is the message hash: `0xc2d48f45d7fbeff644ddb72b0f60df6c275f0943444d7df8cc851b3d55782669`
- Y is x*G, the public key: `(0x2e930f39ba62c6534ee98ed20ca98959d34aa9e057cda01cfd422c6bab3667b7,0x6426529382c23f42b9b08d7832d4fee1d6b437a8526e59667ce9c4e9dcebcabb)`
- r is the r-value: `0x9908144ca6539e09512b9295c8a27050d478fbb96f8addbc3d075544dc413287`
- s is the s-value: `0x1aa528be2b907d316d2da068dd9eb1e23243d97e444d59290d2fddf25269ee0e`
- R is k*G : `(0x9908144ca6539e09512b9295c8a27050d478fbb96f8addbc3d075544dc413287,0x64c226b542a56976625decfa9717d7b649c4b77fed49fe13b770442467a246fa)`
- x is the private key
- k is the signing secret ( aka nonce )

You can play with the equations [in this calculator](https://rawcdn.githack.com/nlitsme/bitcoinexplainer/aa50e86e8c72c04a7986f5f7c43bc2f98df94107/calculator.html#bT0weGMyZDQ4ZjQ1ZDdmYmVmZjY0NGRkYjcyYjBmNjBkZjZjMjc1ZjA5NDM0NDRkN2RmOGNjODUxYjNkNTU3ODI2NjkKWT0oMHgyZTkzMGYzOWJhNjJjNjUzNGVlOThlZDIwY2E5ODk1OWQzNGFhOWUwNTdjZGEwMWNmZDQyMmM2YmFiMzY2N2I3LDB4NjQyNjUyOTM4MmMyM2Y0MmI5YjA4ZDc4MzJkNGZlZTFkNmI0MzdhODUyNmU1OTY2N2NlOWM0ZTlkY2ViY2FiYikKcj0weDk5MDgxNDRjYTY1MzllMDk1MTJiOTI5NWM4YTI3MDUwZDQ3OGZiYjk2ZjhhZGRiYzNkMDc1NTQ0ZGM0MTMyODcKcz0weDFhYTUyOGJlMmI5MDdkMzE2ZDJkYTA2OGRkOWViMWUyMzI0M2Q5N2U0NDRkNTkyOTBkMmZkZGYyNTI2OWVlMGUKUj1mcm9teChyLDApCkcqbStZKnIKUipzCgo=)